# How do you remove spaces from a custom id in Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I tried this in the model:

```
field :_id, type: String, default: ->{ title.gsub(' ', '_') }
```

But, this test is failing on `a = Article.new`:

```
  test 'invalid without a name' do
    a = Article.new
    assert !a.valid?, "Title is not being validated"
  end
```

With:

```
1) Error:
ArticleTest#test_invalid_without_a_name:
NoMethodError: undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass
app/models/article.rb:3:in `block in <class:Article>'
test/models/article_test.rb:6:in `new'
test/models/article_test.rb:6:in `block in <class:ArticleTest>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying problem is that it is trying to assign a default `_id` before there's a `title`. You need a `title` before you can compute the `_id` so you need to defer computing the `_id` until you think you'll have a title. Perhaps `before_validation` hook would make more sense than a default:

```
field :_id, type: String
before_validation :compute_the_id, :unless => :_id
#...
def compute_the_id
  self._id = title.gsub(' ', '_') if(title)
end
```

and then you'd have the usual "make sure we have a title" validation.

Presumably your title field can't change or you'll run into strange case where your `title` and `_id` don't match or you'll be creating whole new documents when a `title` changes or you have a bunch of machinery in place to deal with `_id`s changing. You might guess that I'm recommending against your `_id` plan; you'll probably have a better time overall if you let Mongoid deal with the `_id` in its own way and then add a separate title-slug for URLs and the like.